# How to listen on keydown event in video tag?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a `<video>` tag and want to listen on its keydown event. Below is the code:

html:

```
<div>
<video src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" controls onkeydown="key()">
  </video>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
function key(e) {
  console.log(e.keyCode)
}
```

when I play the video and type some key from keyboard, it doesn't fire the `key` function. what is the correct way to listen on a video key event?

I also tried below code but it doesn't work:

```
document.querySelector("video").onkeydown = function(e) {
  console.log(e.keyCode)
  }
```

Comment: Are you sure need a keydown event? I mean, Video element offers some methods and events for you to track down and do something on video.

https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/video/basics/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get a button press event called, you need to be focused on the element specified. Here, for some reason, you can't focus on the video automatically, so just hack it in when you play the video like this:

```
var video = document.getElementById('vid')

video.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
  console.log(e);
});

video.addEventListener('play', () => {
  video.focus();
});
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/238bygu7/

(Also make sure to add an id to your video in this case)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var video = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0]
video.addEventListener('keypress', function (e) {
  console.log(e)
})
video.addEventListener('playing', function (e) {
  video.focus()
})
```

```html
<video src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" controls></video>
```

The key event is captured only when the DOM element is focus.

Comment: Duplicate answer. Haha

Comment: Oh yeah. I saw the other answer when I clicked the Add Answer button :D

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0].addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
    if(e.key === 'Enter'){
        //Your Code Here
    }
});
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.